# Can i change the style of specific area in body html with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was inspired by an intro logo and want to try implementing it in the website UI. However the more i tried, the more i realized i was just a beginner in website.

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNM8W.png)

```
function getCursorPosition(event) {
  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;

  document.body[x:y].style.filter = blur("0px");
}
```

[This is my code](https://jsfiddle.net/m6dbrv7p/). Can I change the style of specific areas of body html with javascript based on mouse movement?

My expectation is that the body of the website page has filter = blur(5px). So that the specific area reached by the cursor will change its style to filter = blur(0px). Is that possible?

Comment: You cant change CSS in a specific area. Though you can fetch elements within certain bounds and add CSS to them. From your attempt, you can simply position `div` over that specific area and blur it.

Comment: What is `document.body[x:y]` supposed to be? Are you trying to find an element at position (`x`, `y`)? That would be [`document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint). You can’t really make an arbitrary region of your page blurred without having an element at the position (or an extremely complicated SVG filter, if that’s even possible). Did you mean to _move_ an element to the position (`x`, `y`)?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to cover your content area with some elements, leave one of them (at the position of your mouse cursor) transparent and the rest elements that surround transparent element you may blur.

Also, changing the DOM on every `mousemove` (which may be like 200 times per second) is not a good idea. Therefore, you need to do it no more than once for every ~16ms (which is 60fps), otherwise you'll get "junk" frames and laggy behavior. Luckily, you can use `requestAnimationFrame()` for this purpose.

Here is an example of how you can do it (you can also run this snippet with blue button below to see the results live):

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const blurEl = document.querySelector('.blur');
  let curX, curY, isRenderScheduled = false;
  blurEl.addEventListener('mousemove', ({x,y}) => {
      curX = x;
      curY = y;
      if(!isRenderScheduled) {
        isRenderScheduled = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          blurEl.setAttribute('style', `--x:${curX}px;--y:${curY}px`);
          isRenderScheduled = false;
        });
      }
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}
.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
}
.blur > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.blur:before,
.blur:after,
.blur > div:before,
.blur > div:after {
  content: '';
  backdrop-filter:blur(5px);
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
.blur:before {
  min-width: var(--x, auto);
  max-width: var(--x, auto);
}
.blur > div:before {
  min-height: var(--y, auto);
  max-height: var(--y, auto);
}
.transparent {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"> 
  <h1>This is the content</h1>
  <div class="blur" style="--x:auto;--y:auto;">
    <div>
      <div class="transparent"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I used CSS variables on `.blur` element, just because it's not possible to add inline style for pseudo-elements (`:before`, `:after`). If you prefer to use normal elements, you don't need CSS variables.

Answer (score 0):

See [Document.elementFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint)

```js
document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

If you're trying to find multiple elements see [Document.elementsFromPoint()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementsFromPoint)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the best option, because it probably has several usability problems, but adding a blurred `div` with a frame-shaped `clip-path` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) and setting its position everytime the mouse moves could do the trick.

The `div` is blurred, but it's empty on the middle because the `clip-path` value, so you can interact with the body content throw it.

**HTML**

```
<body onmousemove="getCursorPosition(event)">
  <div id="blur" class="blur"></div>
  <div id="kocak">
    <span>My Website</span>
    <div class="cursor-position">The X cursor position is: <span id="cursor-position-x"></span>.</div>
    <div class="cursor-position">The Y cursor position is: <span id="cursor-position-y"></span>.</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getCursorPosition(event) {
  document.getElementById("cursor-position-x").textContent = event.clientX;
  document.getElementById("cursor-position-y").textContent = event.clientY;
  document.getElementById("blur").style.left = event.clientX;
  document.getElementById("blur").style.top  = event.clientY;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 45% 100%, 45% 45%, 55% 45%, 55% 55%, 45% 55%, 45% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```